# Call of unknown method register_block in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I'm using the last version of Smarty, I'm tring to register a block but I get the follow error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Call
>   of unknown method 'register_block'.

I just extended Smarty in my class and then:

```
$this->register_block('myTag', 'myFunction');
```

Why?

Comment: I spend too much time on the same issue. Why doesn't Smarty tag the v2 documentation "warning : obsolete version" !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`register_block()` is Smarty2 API. You're looking for [registerPlugin()](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl) in Smarty 3. You also have the option of using the backward compatibility layer [SmartyBC](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/bc.tpl)

Answer (score 0):

Did you extend Smarty or Smarty_Compiler (I'm not using latest so you need to check what classes there are)

on my older version   class Smarty_Compiler extends Smarty {
so you'd need to change it to  class Smarty_Compiler extends MySmartyVersion {

You could create or amend a plugin to do what you want to do.